# Changing the value of a ConstantExpression in a pre-existing BinaryExpression

Tags: c#, performance, linq, expression-trees

I have some code generating expressions to pass as the "where" statement in a database read, and I'm trying to speed things up a bit.

This example below makes a where statement to match the PK of a table with a passed in value:

```
private Expression MakeWhereForPK(int id)
{
    var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Brand),"b");

    //Expression to get value from the entity
    var leftExp = Expression.Property(paramExp,"ID");

    //Expression to state the value to match (from the passed in variable)
    var rightExp = Expression.Constant(id,typeof(int));

    //Expression to compare the two
    var whereExp = Expression.Equal(leftExp,rightExp);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Brand,bool>>(whereExp,paramExp);
}
```

The above is a simplification for the question - the real thing includes code to take the table to query on and find its PK etc. It is effectively doing the same thing as you might do in code usually:

```
ctx.Brands.Where(b => b.ID = id);
```

This works ok, but, while doing to testing to optimize things a bit I've found its rather slow - doing the above 1000000 times takes around 25 secs. Its better if I omit the last line above (but obviously then it's useless!), so it appears to be Expression.Lamba that taking around 2/3rds of the time, but the rest isn't great either.

If all the queries were going to happen at once I could turn it into an `IN` style expression and generate once, but unfortunately that's not possible, so what I'm hoping for is to save on most of the generation above, and just reuse the generated expression, but passing in a different value of `id`.

Note that, as this is going to be passed to Linq, I can't compile the expression to have an integer parameter that I can pass in on invocation - it must remain as the expression tree.

So the following might be an simple version for the purposes of doing the timing exercise:

```
Expression<Func<Brand,bool>> savedExp;

private Expression MakeWhereForPKWithCache(int id)
{
    if (savedExp == null)
    {
        savedExp = MakeWhereForPK(id);
    }
    else
    {
        var body = (BinaryExpression)savedExp.Body;
        var rightExp = (ConstantExpression)body.Right;

        //At this point, value is readonly, so is there some otherway to "inject" id, 
        //and save on compilation?
        rightExp.Value = id;
    }

    return savedExp;
}
```

How might I re-use the expression, just with a different value of id?

Comment: Would it be an idea to use a [`ParameterExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.parameterexpression.aspx) instead of a `ConstantExpression`?  (Btw, if performance is an issue, why use LINQ at all?  LINQ trades performance for not having to learn SQL.)

Comment: @Andomar: the second `ParameterExpression` will make `Func<Brand, int, bool>`. It can't be used as a predicate for `Where`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change expression trees - they are immutable. But you can replace constant expression via making your own visitor:

```
class MyVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ConstantExpression newIdExpression;

    public MyVisitor(int newId)
    {
        this.newIdExpression = Expression.Constant(newId);
    }

    public Expression ReplaceId(Expression sourceExpression)
    {
        return Visit(sourceExpression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        return newIdExpression;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
            var expr = MakeWhereForPK(0); // p => p.ID == 0
            var visitor = new MyVisitor(1);
            var newExpr = visitor.ReplaceId(expr); p => p.ID == 1
```

Note, that this makes a copy of existing tree.<s>, and I haven't test this for performance. I'm not sure, will this be faster or not.</s>

This code:

```
            // warming up
            var visitor = new MyVisitor(1);
            var expr = MakeWhereForPK(0);
            visitor.ReplaceId(MakeWhereForPK(0));

            var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                MakeWhereForPK(i);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Make expression: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

            sw.Restart();

            for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                visitor.Visit(expr);
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Replace constant expression: {0}", sw.Elapsed);

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

produces these results on my machine:

> Make expression: 00:00:04.1714254
>   Replace constant expression: 00:00:02.3644953
>   Done.

Looks like visitor is faster, than creating a new expression.

Comment: Nice - will look into adopting that - could make a reasonable difference. Thanks

Comment: BTW, your code is somewhat wrong, since it always replaces 0 with 1 (and not `i`). But I don't think that will make any difference in the performance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the fact that the expression tree doesn't have to contain just simple constants, it can also contain property accessed. So, what you would do is to create a single expression that accesses the value of some property, and every time change just that property, not the expression tree.

Something like:

```
class ExpressionHolder
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<Brand, bool>> Expr { get; private set; }

    public ExpressionHolder()
    {
        Expr = MakeWhereForPK();
    }

    private Expression<Func<Brand, bool>> MakeWhereForPK()
    {
        var paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Brand), "b");

        var leftExp = Expression.Property(paramExp, "ID");

        var rightExp = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), "Value");

        var whereExp = Expression.Equal(leftExp, rightExp);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Brand, bool>>(whereExp, paramExp);
    }
}
```

This is about 500× faster than your code: using Dennis's measuring code, I get the following results:

```
Make expression: 00:00:02.9869921
Replace constant expression: 00:00:02.3332857
Set property: 00:00:00.0056485
```

Comment: That's an interesting alternative - it'll require some rework, but, it looks like it'll be worth it.

Comment: Besides the great perf, this is way more versatile because it allows you to change constants even if you don't have the ability to change the expression tree that something is using.

This is what I use, with a `Proxy<T>` class that has `public Expression MakeAccessExpression() => Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), nameof(Proxy<object>.Value));`